# "Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters" from a PowerShell Azure WebJob

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I have the following piece code (extracted from larger script):

```
Write-Output "Syncing $directory"
Push-Location $directory
git pull origin $branch
$directoryName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($directory)    
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H %cd %aN%n%B" --date=short > "..\$directoryName.lastcommit.txt"
Pop-Location
```

Which occasionally (~50% chance) produces an error when run in a Windows Azure WebJob:

```
[05/06/2014 22:20:43 > e5e3ee: INFO] Syncing D:\home\site\!roslyn-sources\DeclarationExpressions
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: ERR ] From https://git01.codeplex.com/roslyn
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: ERR ]  * branch            DeclarationExpressions -> FETCH_HEAD
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: INFO] Already up-to-date.
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: INFO] [ERROR] Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters.
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: INFO] Returning exit code 1
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[05/06/2014 22:20:45 > e5e3ee: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

I never get this error when running locally.

What might be the reason?

Comment: How do you know that it's that part of the script that is causing the problem?

Comment: @Dangph based on the logging in the script -- beginning is marked by _Syncing_ message, and at the end there is another log message just after `Pop-Location` which is not the log if the error happens.

Comment: You can see the full script at https://github.com/ashmind/TryRoslyn/blob/9977126a6d6cbddcb4c7ab4be669749a7d126218/Jobs/Build-Roslyn.ps1 though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, so I don't know what window they could be talking about. I wonder if it is choking on some text in the pipeline that is too long. You could try doing something like `write-output ("x" * 2000)` and see if that causes an error.

Comment: @Dangph good good idea, but it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the exe you are running are changin the Window Title.
So, instead of call `git` directly in your powershell script run it with the cmdlet `Start-Process`